# How to Turn Off Nokia Drive After Reaching Destination?

Tags: lumia, 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, here

When using the Nokia Drive GPS application on a Lumia 920, I'm encountering an issue where once I reach my destination and begin using my phone for other purposes, Nokia Drive is still actively tracking my location in the background.

If I continue driving, it will give me speed limit warnings as well, even though there is no programmed destination and I no longer want the GPS app to be running. Is there any way to avoid this other than turning off the speed limit alerts? I would prefer to be able to shut the GPS off, and imagine this would help save battery life as well.

Comment: Can you please clarify, by turn off do you mean close the app or would you prefer to keep it open but doing nothing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you reach your destination you can press the *back* button and you will be asked if you want to "Stop navigation", select *yes* to exit navigation mode. You can then press the *back* button again to exit the Nokia Drive and have it stop tracking your location.

If you wish to leave Drive open but turn GPS off you will need to navigate through the Drive menus and turn *Location* off and optionality *Connection*. I would suggest that it is easier to just exit the application and open it again when you need it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just pressing the hardware back button once while in the application to close it? This is the first I've heard of double tapping, and when trying it out on my Lumia 920, it just performs two back navigations.

Comment: @G_P just tested and it seems like you are correct. Pressing it twice used to work but it now seems like once is enough http://www.karthikk.net/2011/12/how-to-completely-close-apps-in-windows-phone-7-5-nokia-lumia-800/

Comment: Thanks guys. In the few times I had used the GPS since getting my phone, I always exited the Nokia Drive app by pressing the home button. Alternatively, if you hit the menu button (bottom right corner while in the Drive app), the top option is "Stop Navigation."